# suptitle and title are still misaligned, coordinates conversion notwithstanding

Tags: python, matplotlib

What is my misunderstanding?

I know that something is wrong not only because of the misalignment, but also because `x` doesn't change when I, e.g., use `ax.set_ylabel('x\ny\nz')`: `x` always equals `0.5125` aka 41/80.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')
ax.set_ylim((0, 10))
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ad = ax.transAxes.transform               # axes => display
df = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform # display => figure
x = df(ad((0.5, 1)))[0]
print(x)
ax.set_title('A')
fig.suptitle('A', x=x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_ylabel` adjusts the axis position relative to the figure, but only after the first draw. If you force a draw before computing the transforms, everything checks out.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')
ax.set_ylim((0, 10))
ax.set_ylabel('y')
# --------------------
fig.canvas.draw()
# --------------------
ad = ax.transAxes.transform               # axes => display
df = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform # display => figure
x = df(ad((0.5, 1)))[0]
print(x)
ax.set_title('A')
fig.suptitle('A', x=x)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, that is helpful. I'll probably accept it in a couple of days.